# Speeding up CEF Python in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, chromium-embedded, pyopengl

I am interested in implementing a UI system for my python 3d game engine. Currently, my goal is to use CEF Python to render the GUI using html and custom CSS as this would conveniently handle all 2D layout positioning, text rendering, and user input controls. However, the performance is significantly slower and choppier than it is in the normal chrome browser! Running a WebGL demo in CEF and in the browser, I believe that CEF Python is being capped at 30 FPS, while chrome runs at 60 fps easily.

According to [this](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/240) page, it appears that there is a `windowless_frame_rate` flag that I can set as of version 51 to raise the frame limit. Unfortunately, the version I installed with pip (via `python -m pip install cefpython3`) that is available crossplatform is 31.2. Is there a way on Windows 10, 64bit to install the latest version of CEF Python? From the [github](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython#notifications-on-new-releases) page, it appears that the latest builds are only being maintained for linux. Are there updated builds maintained for windows or instructions for manually building CEF and the python bindings? If not, for anyone using CEF or CEFPython, are there any other tricks to improving performance? I can add the code I have written if needed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: [Issue #240](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/240) provides tips for improving performance in OSR mode. However most of these flags I believe will work only in latest v50+ which is currently available for Linux only.

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Thanks, I have tried various combinations of those flags. `--disable-gpu --disable-gpu-compositing
--enable-begin-frame-scheduling
--disable-d3d11` are all available on 31.2 and do slightly improve performance, but any windowless flag is not available. I also noticed that there was not a PyOpenGL demo in the examples folder in the CEF python github under examples, so if you need a demo to include there, let me know. As a side question, is it possible to pass inputs from say pygame/SDL to CEF in OSR mode? Thanks for making CEF Python by the way, it is exetremely helpful!

Comment: It would be nice if you could share pyopengl demo. Examples in the examples/ directory must be tested against v50+. To submit an example there you would need to create a pull request, however this would go through a strict review. The easiest way to share example is to create a GIST on github and then create a topic on the forum to share the link with other users. I may put a link to it somewhere in docs or wiki as well. Regarding input question: yes, take a look at the Browser object and its SendXxxxx methods. Take a look at Kivy/Panda3d examples on wiki pages.